# Is std::random_shuffle reproducible across different compilers?

Tags: c++

I am using the `std::random_shuffle` function with a custom random number generator that, for the same seed, returns the same sequence of random numbers across all compilers.

However, I'm concerned `std::random_shuffle` may not use the same algorithm between different compilers, and therefore, for the same seed, the result won't be the same.

Can I rely on `std::random_shuffle` producing the same output across different compilers with the same sequence of random numbers provided? If not, any alternatives?

Not using C++11 or Boost.

Comment: So you want a sequence of numbers that aren't random?

Comment: No, he want the same randomness for a given seed on different compilers.

Comment: I don't see anything in the standard that would even require one implementation to always produce the same result, much less different implementations.

Comment: I compared the reference implementation here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/ with my compiler's standard library, and they give different results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From reading "25.3.12 Random shuffle" in the C++11 standard (the one I have here) I would conclude that strictly spoken that guarantee can not be made. The only requirement for the algorithm is "that each possible permutation of those elements has equal probability of appearance". It does not have to swap the elements front to back, for example, and the iterators are random access iterators so that any other order is possible. (That said, I'd be surprised if an implementation wouldn't go first -> last, but it's not guaranteed.)